# How to unclog nozzles on massaging shower heads?

Tags: bathroom

This previous question was more about cleaning the shower head and not specifically unclogging the nozzles.  I have a Speakerman Anystream 2000 massaging showerhead whose nozzles are so clogged that only a trickle of water comes out now.  There were alot of hard water stains that I cleaned off and tried various things but it is still clogged.

Comment: You can soak the head in a Calcium, Lime, and Rust Removing Bathroom cleaner, I would check the progress of the removal of the clogs two to three times a day, first with a simple visual inspection. Then when you think that the clogs might be gone, run water through it to make sure, either rinsing well and re-installing the shower head, or placing back in the cleaning solution to soak more. I have also heard of vinegar working, but am not sure how well, as I have never used it. I have also manually sped up the process by using a small blunt pin to clear the nozzles, very carefully. good luck!!

Comment: @Navajo why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have hard water and we use a combination of physics and chemistry.

Physics: rub your thumbnail hard across the little holes, and usually the scale will flake away. Some people are also fans of poking toothpicks, safety pins etc into the holes.

Chemistry: get some [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_Lime_Rust). Either remove the shower head and set it in a bowl of CLR, or do what they show on TV and hold the bowl up to the in-place shower head for a while. (If I were to do that I would wear goggles just in case.) You can reuse the CLR to clear scale off other nearby things after doing the shower head.

Comment: If you poke, try to backflush the residue out of the shower head so it does not plug the holes again. I have used a garden sprayer on "jet" or an air compressor.

Answer (score 2):

Take a baggie, fill it with Vinegar and tie it around the shower head and let it soak over night.   Remove the baggie and flush with water.  The vinegar, being acid dissolves the lime which is a base.  Alternatively, if it's easy to unscrew the shower head, remove it and soak it in a small bowl of Vinegar.  Vinegar is a lot less expensive than commercial cleaners and does a remarkably good job.  Vinegar is a great to have around the house:

http://www.allyou.com/budget-home/organizing-cleaning/uses-for-vinegar

Comment: I've always used vinegar for cleaning and unclogging shower heads. It worked great on my massaging shower head.

Answer (score 1):

Soaking it in vinegar will remove build ups from hard water.